# MVC in PHP - How does the controller know the view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC in PHP and I was just wondering what the best way to do this is?
At the moment I've got a simple setup like this:

- Model

  - User.php
- Controller

  - controller.php
- View

  - login.php
  - register.php
  - my_account.php

The model has all the database functionality for logging in and registering, and the view files have the relevant working forms.

My main question is, what is the best way to have the controller call pages? Currently, it looks something like:

```
public function show_page()
{
  if ($_GET['p'] == "login")
  { 
     include('View/login.php'); 

     if (isset($_POST['username']))
     {
        $this->user->login($_POST['username'], $_['pass']
     }

  }
  if ($_GET['p'] == "register") { include('View/register.php'); }
  if ($_GET['p'] == "my_account") { include('View/my_account.php'); }
}
```

This doesn't seem logical, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Although it's perfectly fine to implement an MVC model in raw php, I strongly recommend using a framework such as [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com) (there are many others out there)

Comment: "am I doing it wrong": Yes, you're writing your own MVC framework instead of using an existing one.

Comment: Rolling your own is a good learning experience.  Besides, Zend is far from perfect.  Having said that, for production code a pre-build framework, especially one with a comprehensive test suite, is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Urgh, I'm sick of people telling me to use an existing framework. I **know** there are better frameworks out there already, but by creating my own from scratch it means I actually understand the basis of how they work rather than stumbling around in my logical blindness trying to figure out how a much bigger (and better) existing one works.

Comment: @Tommo Very well said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best way is to use some kind of **routing** system so you have a map somewhere with the possible url pattern / page to show combinations and after deciding **which controller to call** you can load the appropriate view in your controller.

What you presented here seems somewhat blurred to me. I think that you should check out implementations out there like [Pure mvc](http://puremvc.org/) or [symfony](http://symfony.com/) so you can get a grip on the concept quickly. I believe that you (or anyone else for that matter) **shouldn't reinvent the wheel** but study, understand and improve what you can get.

If you are going to create your own MVC framework then you should check out the [basic MVC concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and **plan your software** before trying to write it.

Comment: So should every page have its own controller? A controller for the login page, registration page and my_account page?

Comment: @Tommo no a controller for all pages (if ness) and a function for each page (and a view to go with each)

Comment: Ah cool, so something more like this would be better?

public function show_page()
{
  if ($_GET['page'] == 'login')
  {
    $this->login();
  }
}

Comment: The basic idea is to have a controller for every logically coherent set of pages and one view for every function of it. So /user/register for registration /user/view/username for viewing a profile can belong to the same controller with 2 different views.

Comment: But what I'm asking is how the functions in the controller are called? How does the controller know what view to show and what function to load, without having a load of IF statements checking every GET variable.

Comment: I think that a context object can decide which method to call according to the routing table and harmonize the components of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Most PHP based MVC frameworks that I've used utilize a *front controller*.  The .htaccess file directs all traffic to a single (usually index.php) file (usually) in the root of the project.

This file is responsible for determining which *application* controller to load.  That controller is then responsible for any and all application level logic.

in a framework I wrote, in my **front controller** I do this

```
$page = tgsf_parse_url();
require resolve_controller( $page );
```

The [tgsf_parse_url](http://code.google.com/p/tgsf/source/browse/trunk/tgsf_core/tgSimpleFramework.php#458) function in the above code parses `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` to determine what variables are being passed.

the [resolve_controller](http://code.google.com/p/tgsf/source/browse/trunk/tgsf_core/tgSimpleFramework.php#616) in the above code handles plugin hooks and 404 conditions, but the bottom line is that it always returns a path to send to include/require so that variable scoping doesn't become an issue (including in a function limits variable scope)

Any variables that are set in the controller are automatically available in a view when you include a view like this:

```
// this is an application level controller file
$name = 'Mr. Example';
include view( 'example' );
```

Then in the view file:

```
<h2><? echo $name; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not dynamic at all.

This is how I do it in [my MVC](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry):

```
private function loadView(){        

    //Bring the variables to the global scope
    extract($this->getAll()); //load all variables into local scope

    if(Config::get('view')){
        $template_file = 'view/' . Config::get('view') . '/' . Config::get('method') . '.stp';
        if(is_file($template_file)){
            include $template_file;
        }
        else {
            include 'view/missingview.stp'; //no such view error
        }
    }
    else {
        Config::set('template', 'blank');
        include 'view/missingfunction.stp'; //no such function error
    }

}
```

Have something set the `view` somewhere in the code.

This is how I set the `view` in the controller:

```
public function __construct(SessionManager $SESSION) {

    $this->pageOn = Config::get('page');
    $this->session = $SESSION;
    $model_name = $this->name;
    if(class_exists($model_name) && is_subclass_of($model_name, 'AppModel')){
        /**
         * @var AppModel $model_name
         */
        $this->$model_name = new $model_name();
    }
    else {
        //default model (no database table chosen)
        $this->$model_name = new AppModel();
    }
    /* Get all posts */
    $this->posts = $this->$model_name->getPosts();

    Config::set('view', strtolower($model_name)); //<<RIGHT HERE!

    if(!$this->session->get(strtolower($model_name))){
        $this->session->set(strtolower($model_name), array());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry to dumbify your system too much here, but does this basically look at the value of $_GET['page'] and load 'view/*value of page*.stp'

Comment: Edited the comment above there!